# Github Enterprise Raw URL Gist Unable to Download

Tags: api, github

I'm able to get a list of gists and their files https://api.git.mygithub.net/users/myuser/gists?per_page=100&page=1 which I found using the docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/gists#get-a-gist

The files on the gist object have a `raw_url`.  If I fetch the raw_url with the same token, it fails wanting me to authenticate.  If I add the header: `Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw` it returns a 406 Not Acceptable.  I've references to that header around.

I'm not sure what the scope should be on the token.  It seems like it would be the same one I accessed the API.  In the UI if you click the raw file it gets a token appended to the url.  That token doesn't look like one of the Private tokens mentioned here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

So what is the format of the HTTP request to download the raw gist?

Comment: Does your token have the `gist` scope?

Comment: It does.  Tried it both with query params and Auth header.

Answer (score 0):

The raw url needs to have the hostname of `gist.` changed to `raw.` and the url path needs to start with `/gist/`.

Example code in Go fixing it:

```
    url := gistFile.RawUrl
    url = strings.Replace(url, "gist.", "raw.", 1)
    url = strings.Replace(url, ".net/", ".net/gist/", 1)
```